# Plot a multiple geom_smooth curve instead of single

Tags: r, ggplot2, categories

I am plotting a graph with 6 different categories (years) that are represented by different colours. I want one curve per categorie to represent the trend of each year, but when I use geom_smooth I get only one single curve. Additionally I have the problem, that I can't change the colours of my categories. Do you have any tips?  My code is:

```
year_1999<-subset(count_all, year.x<=2004)
first.plot<-ggplot(year_1999, aes(temperature, ENS, col=year.x))+
geom_point(shape=17)+
geom_smooth(aes(fill=year.x))+
scale_color_manual(values = c("green","darkorange","darkblue", "darkgrey", "yellow","red"))+ #doesn't work
ylab("ENS")+
xlab("Temperature [°C]")+
ggtitle("1999-2004")+
labs(color = "Year")+
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=18,colour="black",vjust=0.7),axis.text.y=element_text(size=12,face="bold",colour="black",angle=0,hjust=0.9))+
theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=18,colour="black",vjust=0.2),axis.text.x=element_text(size=12,colour="black",face="bold"))+
theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank())+
theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.2,0.2,.2,0.2),"cm"))+
theme(panel.border=element_rect(colour="black",size=1.5))+
theme(axis.ticks=element_line(colour="black",size=1),axis.ticks.length=unit(0.3,"cm"))

first.plot`
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Most likely reason is that `year.x` is a numeric in which case you could try with `geom_smooth(aes(group = year.x))`.

Comment: It works! @stefan Do you also have an idea how to change the colours?